# Batch script If command on a String

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, string, echo

What is wrong with the following command lines for my batch script?

```
set test=BE99012345678901


if %test% == "BE99????????????"(
echo This number begins with BE99
)
Else (
echo This number doesn't begin with BE99
)
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
set test=BE99012345678901

if "%test:~0,4%"=="BE99" (
echo This number begins with BE99
) else (
echo This number doesn't begin with BE99
)
pause
```

You will get following output:

`This number begins with BE99`

Kindly note:

`if %test% == "BE99????????????"` will do this:
`"BE99012345678901" == "BE99????????????"`

and this will show following output:

`This number doesn't begin with BE99`

Comment: isn't %test% only a cmd/DOS syntax, no valid in *nix, whereas what you have written is bash, so $test would be the thing to use in the if in your case. Though he did specify batch(so, cmd no doubt).

Comment: Barlop you are correct, thanks for mentioning that.
I have made changes in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

barlop's answer covers most of your problems.  It should also be noted that you need the `ELSE` to be on the same line as the closing parenthesis for the `IF`.  Like so:

```
IF "%var%"=="whatever" (
  REM Do stuff
) ELSE (
  REM Do other stuff
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't use question mark or any wildcard in that a==b line  The == operator doesn't take ? as special, it takes it as literal. And it doesn't look at filenames either.  So, that just goes to prove it really does just take ? as literal.

Also, in Linux if you did echo ?  it would be interpreted by the shell before it goes to the echo command and it would return a filename of one char length. In Windows ? or * are not interpreted by the shell, they are passed to a command. DIR uses ? and *, treats them as special, ECHO doesn't, and the test for equality if == doesn't, and it would just echo a question mark.   I doubt what you wrote there would be valid in bash either. As in linux ? and * are always to do with filenames and you seem to want purely for the variable comparison.

```
C:\a>touch BE99 <---- a gnuwin32 touch line to create a file called BE99

C:\a>if BE99==BE9? echo true

C:\a>if "BE99"=="BE9?" echo true

C:\a>

C:\a>dir BE9? /b
BE99

C:\a>
```

So, ? works with DIR, but not with a==b

But besides that, if you do  "4"==4 then it will say false, as you have to do quotes around both or around neither.  The reason for quotes is if you do %var%==%var% and %var% is empty then you have a syntax error because it works by substitution, substitution so you get nothing on either side of the == so just if ==. So better to use quotes, than no quotes. Some use []. if [%var%]==[%var%]

You can use this

```
C:\a>set test=BE9923432423

C:\a>echo %test:~0,4%
BE99
```

So, in your code you could do `if "%test:~0,4%"=="BE99" (`